# How to extend life time of session?

Tags: orbeon

I have an application in which I include an XForms form with Orbeon 3.9.

My form when left for about 5 minutes displays message dialog about the session being expired.

How can I extend the lifetime of form session to the time when user will close his browser?

This app will have not many users and will be idle most of the time so efficiency is not a problem.

//edit

I've just noticed that when I open multiple forms in their own tabs only last opened form has non expired session, in rest of them I see "Session has expired" dialog box.

Orbeon can handle more than one form being filled by same user in same time?

Comment: Yes Orbeon Forms can definitely handle more than one form at the same time, although 3.9 is a release of Orbeon Forms which is 5-6 years-old and I am not sure of all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can set a Java web application's session in the WAR file's `web.xml` with the `<session-config>` element. For example this sets the session timeout to 60 minutes.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

You can extend the session duration accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've updated my question.